# Register one of many types to an interface using Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

Autofac has a TON of registration techniques, most of which I have trouble understanding. Reading through the docs for a while, I didn't see anything that would allow me to do this.

I have a system outside of my control that, based on some command line parameters, instantiates a certain class. This class is one of many that all derive from a common base class. For example:

```cs
abstract class BaseCommand {}
class CommandOne : BaseCommand {}
class CommandTwo : BaseCommand {}
```

I won't know until *after* component registration which derived class (either `CommandOne` or `CommandTwo`) will be constructed by this library. Here's a rough outline of what the code looks like:

```cs
static void Main() {
  // Do all the autofac registrations
  IContainer container = CompositionRoot.Setup();

  // Parse command line arguments
  ParseCommandLine(type => container.Resolve(type))
}
```

The `ParseCommandLine()` method is the "black box" code that constructs either of the two classes I mentioned before. It does so by invoking the lambda I pass to it. It will *never* instantiate both classes, but only one of them.

What I need is for Autofac to allow me to "lazy register" `BaseCommand` as a service. That is to say, at registration time, we don't know which specific context will be chosen but we know it will always be derived from `BaseCommand`. So something roughly like this:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(ctx => /*Access the type passed to Resolve() and instantiate that*/).As<BaseCommand>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
```

So essentially what I want is:

1. We can only ever have 1 concrete type registered for `BaseCommand`
2. We don't know what that implementation is until resolve happens
3. We use the type provided to `Resolve()` to decide
4. We will only ever have a single instance of that type.
5. An attempt to resolve any other concrete type should fail (for example, once I resolve type `CommandOne`, resolving `CommandTwo` should throw an exception)

How can I accomplish this in Autofac?

Comment: You can't register at the same time as resolve. When do you actually know the type? Is it a parameter on command line? Config option? Update the question to include that.

Comment: I thought I made it clear enough. There's 2 commands. The library that parses those commands creates 1 of those two types depending on which option was passed. What is known at startup is there are 2 possible implementations for my service, but only the type passed to the lambda is the implementation that should be instantiated.

Comment: to modify the behaviors of ***back boxes***, you have 2 options: intercept its input or intercept its output. In this case I think the option 1 is better (as long as you can predict the output based on the input). You cannot do much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're going to be able to get 100% of what you want, but I think you can get pretty close with a bit of indirection.

First, you'll need a sort of mediator thing that can be used in lambda expressions so you can delay the actual registration contents. It has a few jobs:

- Store the selected type that the black box picks. This way it can be used in the lambda to "defer" figuring out which of the commands were selected.
- Register the available commands, but with a random "key" so they don't accidentally get resolved. The container is immutable so you can't "unregister" things later, and anything you need to resolve (or potentially resolve) needs to be registered.
- Resolve the available command, but using a filter so you get the selected one.

It'll look something like this:

```cs
public static class CommandFilter
{
  private static readonly Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();

  public static Type SelectedCommand { get; set; }

  public static void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, Type type)
  {
    // The "secret key" will be required to resolve these,
    // so container.Resolve<T>() won't work - it'd have
    // to be container.ResolveKeyed<T>(_id) to get it.
    builder.RegisterType(type).Keyed(type, _id);
  }

  public static BaseCommand Resolve(IComponentContext context)
  {
    // Only resolve the selected implementation, everything else
    // stays "hidden."
    return context.ResolveKeyed(_id, CommandFilter.SelectedCommand) as BaseCommand;
  }
}
```

Now you need to register all the `BaseCommand` implementations but using this filter thing. That means some manual assembly scanning for you.

```cs
// WARNING: I can never remember the right direction for
// IsAssignableFrom so check this by testing.
var asm = typeof(BaseCommand).Assembly;
foreach(var type in asm.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(BaseCommand).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
{
  // Register your "secret" keyed registrations.
  CommandFilter.Register(builder, type);
}

// Register the BaseCommand itself.
builder.Register(ctx => CommandFilter.Resolve(ctx))
  .As<BaseCommand>()
  .SingleInstance();
```

In your black box, the key will be to FIRST set the filter type, THEN resolve.

```cs
ParseCommandLine(type => {
  CommandFilter.SelectedCommand = type;
  container.Resolve<BaseCommand>();
});
```

The lambda in the registration allows you to defer selection; the lambda passed to `ParseCommandLine` can take the selection; and only the one you want will be resolved. Everything else is registered but effectively inaccessible, and carte blanche calls to `container.Resolve<NotTheSelectedCommand>()` will fail with a resolution exception because they're registered as *keyed* and will require the key to resolve.

I haven't actually run this through a compiler, but it seems like this should do the trick. Depending on the "real" system, you may need to put a lock around where the `SelectedCommand` gets set because, while `container.Resolve<T>()` is thread-safe, you've got that selection mechanism running outside it. Might also need some error handling for folks trying to resolve from the command filter before `SelectedCommand` is set, that sort of thing.